# How to get input with special characters in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I figured console output with special characters(é ü ğ ö ş) with locale::global() function. But couldn't find any way to get input with those special characters.

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
cout << str;
```

When I type "Léon ç.ş.ö.ü"

> L'on ┼.Y.".?

This is the output. How can i fix this?

EDIT: Problem is fixed. My setlocale command was right under the main function. All I did is setting locale somewhere else. When I do this. It just worked fine. I don't know why.

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
cout << str;    
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
```

EDIT 2: This works much better. Works with file i/o too.

```
#include <Windows.h>
SetConsoleOutputCP(1254);
SetConsoleCP(1254);
```

Comment: Firstly, show the code ([mcve]) and observations. Then, be aware that this strongly depends on the environment that the program output is displayed in, so add that info, too.

Comment: Have you tried changing the locale: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale

Comment: I had setlocale command already. And appeared that was breaking my strings. When i remove it my problem is solved but this doesn't work anymore: cout << "ç ş ö ğ"

Comment: Have you tried `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` that should set the program locale to the locale of the process that runs it.

Comment: that fixes the console output with cout << "ç ş ö ğ". But broke the string output again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting setlocale command somewhere else then right under the main function worked. It was like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
string str;
getline(cin, str);
cout << str;
```

This fixed all strings and outputs on my program:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
cout << str;    
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
```